# C - Deleting any node from a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I ran into some trouble while attempting to remove a Node form a doubly linked list. While I can generally remove the nodes, the moment I attempt to remove the first element, it crashes my program and returns Error 3221225477.

I create my list with a header, like this:

```
typedef struct Inode2*Task;                                     
typedef struct Inode2{
        int ID;
        int Priority;
        int Status;
        char *Description;
        Person *person;
        Date   *creation;
        Date   *deadline;
        Date   *conclusion;                             
        Task next;
        Task previous;
    }Task_node2;    

Task TaskCreate()                                                                                                           {
    Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(Task));
    aux->next=NULL;
    aux->previous=NULL;
    return aux;
}
```

So as far as I'm aware, this is creating a list with a header, which is given to me to manipulate further.

I have a function to insert a node at the tail of this List. That seems to be working perfectly.

Whenever I use this removal function on the first element, it crashes:

```
int TaskRemove(Task h,int IDREMOVE)                                                                                         {
    int val;
    for(;h;h=h->next)
    {
        if (h->ID==IDREMOVE)
        {
            h->previous->next = h->next;
            val++;
            if (h->previous->previous==NULL)
            {
                h->previous->next = h->next;
            }
        }
    }
    if (val==0)
    {
        printf("\n\tNo node with such ID\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return val;
}
```

This works on every element but the last. What's happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: `typedef struct Inode2*Task;` oh, don't typedef pointers. Especially not to a strange name like `Task`. Your code will be unreadable for others and - probably - also yourself

Comment: Your first bug (due to type def of pointer) is here: `Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(Task));`. Should be (at least) `Task aux=malloc(sizeof(struct Inode2));` but better would be: `Task_node2* aux=malloc(sizeof *aux);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code accesses a two-away node without checking if the corresponding one-away node exists. Deleting the last node in the list will give you a similar problem.

You need to `NULL`-check each pointer before applying `->` operator to it. Specifically, the code that checks `h->previous->previous == NULL` needs to first make sure that `h->previous` is not `NULL`. You need to add `NULL` checking of the first pointer in all places where you do a two-away check or assignment.

**Note:** Your code has other issues, for example, `malloc(sizeof(Task))` yields memory of incorrect size. The root case of the confusion is that `Task` is a pointer type, but it is used without an asterisk. You should avoid this situation if possible by using `Inode2*` directly or by renaming `Inode2` to `Task` for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

First issue with your code is how you allocate memory for a node.

```
Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(Task));
```

This line allocates `sizeof(Task)` bytes of memory. `Task` is a pointer, not the actual node. Depending on the compiler, it most likely will allocate just enough space for a pointer. You should use the following to allocate space for `Inode2`:

```
Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(struct Inode2));
```

The second issue is in these lines:

```
h->previous->next = h->next;
val++;
if (h->previous->previous==NULL)
{
    h->previous->next = h->next;
}
```

For the first element, `h->previous` should be `NULL`, so when you try to access `h->previous->next`, the program is trying to access a `NULL` pointer, which causes the crash. You have to check if `h->previous` is `NULL` or not before trying to access further.

#### Notes:

- As mentioned in a comment, do **NOT** typedef pointers.
- You said it crashes on the *first* element, then said it works on every element but the *last*. I'm assuming the former.